# Adding Class to the Body of pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element, window.open

[image: See my code here]

I want to add a class to a certain pop-up window.

For example, when I `window.open()` facebook.com, I want to add a class that disables the scrolling of that page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please paste your code into your question, not adding screenshot of your code

Comment: no, it is not possible to do what you want

Comment: By the way, adding an arbitrary class is unlikely to do what you require - do you know that the class you want to add has any effect at all?

Comment: so there's no way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the window you want to open is from the same origin else you get the `DOMException: cross-origin` error when accessing it's DOM within your script.

If you are able to add the class (possible when some origin), just be sure that the CSS is defined for the class you are adding to the element in the page.

Comment: clearly the question is about a cross origin window - unless the OP works for facebook (highly doubtful)

Comment: so there's no way of doing this?

Comment: yeah. Don't think it is possible.